# Combine artifacts with different groupId for Maven resolving

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Can I tell Maven to treat artifacts with different group ids to be the same?

As an example, If two dependencies pull in the following two artifacts transitively,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

both of them will be included.

Maven will not recognize that both artifacts are actually the same and that version 1.3.9 is the newer and should be taken.

Comment: By using which algorithm should it make that decision? An artifact is identified by groupId+artifactId + version .. ?

Comment: That's why I ask the question. I can think of a plug-in for example. It seems to be a common issue. JAXB moving to Jakarta e.g. is another issue like this. Now I have to manually exclude the old dependency from many packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you requested. But you could at least fail the build if there are duplicate classes with an enforcer rule:

https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html

Comment: Might be a limited solution...and will at least put your attention that there might be an issue...

Comment: Thanks, that is at least avoids having conflicts in the code base. Even if I have to manage it by myself.